# Select all rows where all array values are present in another column

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have two tables:

```
--------------------------------
| user_id  | permissions        |
---------------------------------
|    1     | ['perm1', 'perm2'] | 
---------------------------------
|    2     | ['perm1']          |
---------------------------------

----------------------------------------
| integration_id | permissions_required |
-----------------------------------------
|       1        |   ['perm1']          |
-----------------------------------------
|       2        |   ['perm2']          |
-----------------------------------------
|       3        |   ['perm1', 'perm2'] |
------------------------------------------
```

I'd Like to be able to query all integrations that a specific user has access to. I've been searching for a while but I'm fairly new to using mysql to this extent.

How would I go about querying these tables to find all integrations where the user has all the required permissions?

EDIT: I realise I didn't mention the permissions & permissions_required columns are JSON columns. Based on the accepted answer I'm going to bring up the topic of restructuring our database permissions to use traditional many->many instead of arrays

Comment: Do you have control over the tables structure? I mean, could you create a different table?

Comment: So in your example user_id 1 would have integrations 1,2,3 and user_id 2 would have 1?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, that's correct. :)

Comment: @StefanoZanini I don't, unfortunately. I could potentially persuade the decision to add another table, though I was hoping to avoid that if possible

Comment: I wrote a long answer assuming you could change the structure. I posted it anyways because I think it's a good answer and may be helpful for others, but of course ignore it if it's not applicable for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a clear example of why storing comma separated values in a single column is a bad idea. With the design you have, you will need to split strings (MySQL doesn't even have a built-in function for that) and then join tables based on the result of splits.

The task you want to do would be incredibly easier on a properly designed tables schema.

Starting from scratch, your entities are `user`, `integration` and `permission`, thus you need a table for each of them.

```
User: id, name, whatever_else
Integration: id, description, whatever_else
Permission: id, description, whatever_else
```

The relationship between `user` and `permission` is `many-to-many`, because each `user` can have multiple `permissions` and each `permission` can be given to multiple `users`: you want to model this with another table then

```
UserPermission: userID, permissionID
```

Same holds for the relationship between `permission` and `integration`: each `integration` may require multiple `permissions`, each `permission` can be required for multiple `integrations`.

```
IntegrationPermission: integrationID, permissionID
```

Your sample data would then be look like this

```
User
id | name
1  | User1
2  | User2

Permission
id | desc
1  | Perm1
2  | Perm2

UserPermission
userID | permissionID
1      | 1
1      | 2
2      | 1

Integration
id | desc
1  | Integration1
2  | Integration2
3  | Integration3

IntegrationPermission
integrationID | permissionID
1             | 1
2             | 2
3             | 1
3             | 2
```

Now the query: the tricky part is taking the users that have all the permissions required for an integration. Let's build this in a few steps.

First of all, we combine the two relationship tables to get user, integration and the number of permission a user has for that integration

```
select  t1.userID,
        t2.integrationID,
        count(distinct t2.permissionID) as userIntegrationPermissions
from    userPermission t1
join    integrationPermission t2
on      t1.permissionID = t2.permissionID
group by t1.userID, t2.integrationID
```

Then, we need the count of the permissions required for each integration

```
select  integrationID,
        count(permissionID) permCount
from    integrationPermission
group by integrationID
```

Finally we join these two, adding User and Integration tables to get the descriptions (this is optional of course)

```
select  tt3.id, tt3.name, tt4.id, tt4.desc
from    (
            select  t1.userID,
                    t2.integrationID,
                    count(distinct t2.permissionID) as userIntegrationPermissions
            from    UserPermission t1
            join    IntegrationPermission t2
            on      t1.permissionID = t2.permissionID
            group by t1.userID, t2.integrationID
        ) tt1
join    (
            select  integrationID,
                    count(permissionID) permCount
            from    IntegrationPermission
            group by integrationID
        ) tt2
on      tt1.integrationID = tt2.integrationID and
        tt1.userIntegrationPermissions = tt2.permCount
join    User tt3
on      tt1.userID = tt3.id
join    Integration tt4
on      tt1.integrationID = tt4.id
order by 1, 3
```

You can fiddle with it at [this link (rextester)](http://rextester.com/JUZ16586)